# Copy files across servers in a weekly basis

Tags: mysql, replication, rsync

I want to create a cronjob to synchronize two servers on a weekly basis. I have two servers A and B and I want to synchronize the files and mysql databases to the second server on a weekly basis. I think rsync can be used to synchronize the files. But how can I synchronize the database ?

Thanks,

Comment: are both databases in active use?

Comment: did you tried replication? it's a real time sync. you can't go with rsync if you do not want shutdown your database.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create a script that will restore the database to the remote server.

``` mysqldump -u username -ppassword  database_name | mysql -u Username_remote -ppassword_remote --host=remote_server_IP -C databse_name >> ``date "+%Y-%m-%d" ```.log`
This is not the best way to do this and not recommended in live servers.